# How can I break an unordered list into columns at specific points?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to break a list of menu items into columns at specific points.

```
<ul>
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text1</li>

    <li class="br"></li>
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text2</li>    
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text2</li>

    <li class="br"></li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text3</li>
</ul>
```

The breaks should occur at the `li` elements with class `br`, breaking the next set of `li`'s onto a new column.

Example of the intended layout:
|     |     |     |
|-----|-----|-----|
|text1|text2|text3|
|text1|text2|text3|
|text1|text2|text3|
|     |text2|text3|
|     |text2|     |

**UPDATE:**
I couldn't get the look-and-feel I wanted using the `ul` element so I ended up using `div`'s.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wa4bL7qf/) with the approach I ended up taking that may help anyone else in the future.

Comment: Don't you want to use a simple `table`?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 - it's for a menu dropdown - adding/removing items on it won't be as convenient as just adding/removing an `li` from the `ul`

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like this ...
also, you can use flex proparty

```css
li{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text2</li>    
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text2</li>

   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to preferably keep it contained in a single list

Answer (score 0):

```css
.list{
  width: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
ul{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li{
  padding: 0px 1%;
  margin: 0;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 24%;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n){
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>test3</li>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>test3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From you markup, grid and grid-column can be used with a sibbling selector:

example

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 0 2em;
}

li {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.br {
  display: none;
}

li.br~li {
  grid-column: 2;
}

li.br~.br~li {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text1</li>

  <li class="br"></li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text2</li>

  <li class="br"></li>
  <li>text3</li>
  <li>text3</li>
  <li>text3</li>
  <li>text3</li>
</ul>
```

More about grid : gridbyexample.com/ & https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ t start with ;)